# Why does my SELECT query not return null values?

Tags: postgresql, null, postgresql-11

I have the following SQL script:

```
CREATE temporary table if not EXISTS the_values (
 key SERIAL,
 value INTEGER NULL 
);

insert into the_values(value) values (null),(1),(null),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(10),(null),(null);

select * 
from the_values 
where value not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,10);
```

And I noticed that the query:

```
select * 
from the_values 
where value not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,10);
```

Does not return the rows having `value` NULL, and that caught my attention. Therefore, I want to know why that happens. I am interested more about the technical aspect of this phenomenon rather that the obvious solution:

```
select * 
from the_values 
where value not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,10) 
   or value IS NULL;
```

Comment: because you should check for `values is null or not in (...`

Comment: But null value is not in the array to begin with so obviously the select it should return values with null.

Comment: Null values have an specific treatment, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff08fcec471189c8b90a47dd9274158a and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify the insert and query to:

```
insert into T(x) values (null),(1);

select x from T where x not in (1);
```

For null the predicate will evaluate to:

```
select x from T where null not in (1) <=>
select x from T where not null in (1) <=>
select x from T where not null <=>
select x from T where null
```

so that row does not satisfy the predicate. If you try to compare something with null (think of it as unknown), the result will be null.

For 1 the predicate will evaluate to:

```
select x from T where 1 not in (1) <=>
select x from T where False
```

so that row does not satisfy the predicate either

I.e. you end up with an empty result

Answer (score 2):

Generally, **avoid `NOT IN`** when `NULL` values can be involved on either side. The [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN) suggests as much. And avoid `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` in any case. The Wiki has the explanation. And also happens to have the perfect answer to your core question:

> 1. `NOT IN` behaves in unexpected ways if there is a null present:

> ```
> select * from foo where col not in (1,null); -- always returns 0 rows
> ```

> ```
> select * from foo where col not in (select x from bar);   -- returns 0 rows if any value of bar.x is null
> ```

> This happens because `col IN (1,null)` returns `TRUE` if `col=1`, and `NULL`
> otherwise (i.e. it can never return `FALSE`). Since `NOT (TRUE)` is `FALSE`,
> but `NOT (NULL)` is still `NULL`, there is no way that `NOT (col IN (1,null))` (which is the same thing as col `NOT IN (1,null))` can return
> `TRUE` under any circumstances.

Here is a maybe not so obvious solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   the_values 
WHERE  value IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,10) IS NOT TRUE;
```

Or:

```
..
WHERE  value = ANY('{1,2,3,4,5,6,10}') IS NOT TRUE;
```

It's shorter and typically faster than your "obvious" one.

For *long* lists, consider switching to a different (faster) technique:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)