# How do I send an array of strings to PG from PHP without the former becoming confused?

Tags: postgresql, php, array, string

I want to do this, but for more than one string:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE label <> $1
```

That selects all records from `table` where the `label` column is different from a single string. It works.

But now I want to do the same, but instead of just checking a single string, I have an array of strings in PHP, `[ 'ignore string 1', 'ignore string 2', 'ignore string 3' ]`,  which I wish to have excluded.

If I just send an array of strings to that same query for the $1, it gives errors. I've tried a lot of things now. I even attempted:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE label NOT IN $1
```

But that doesn't work for an application-provided array of strings.

Do I simply need to do `::array` to convert it or something? I couldn't get it to work either.

Yes, it's most common to have a different table in the database with "ignore phrases", but in this case, I need to provide a list of such strings as an array from the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE label <> ALL ($1);
```

Then you can pass an actual ***array*** for `$1` - while (`NOT`) `IN` expects a ***list*** of values. See:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860)

If NULL values can be involved on either side, either query is problematic. You may want the form:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (label = ANY ($1) IS NOT TRUE);
```

See:

- [Why does my SELECT query not return null values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270265/why-does-my-select-query-not-return-null-values/270292#270292)